# arm64-v8a Build Variant not showing up in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How can I make `arm64-v8a` show up in Build Variant section?

[image]

I'm using the following setup on macOS:

```
Android Studio 3.4.1 
Gradle Version 3.3
android-ndk-r15c
compileSdkVersion = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

put this code in build gradle

```
splits {
      abi {
          enable true
          reset()
          include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"

          }
       }
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits)